# Change all values in RMarkdown html document to NA or 0

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-manipulation

I have a large RMarkdown document containing data.
Now I want to show the document but without data to display the how the document will look without any input data.

I want each value to show as 0 or NA.

Is there a way to pass a global argument to the Rmarkdown document to change all the values?

The issue I am having is that data is being read from many files so it is onerous to change each individual dataset to 0 or NA.

I am using the "kable" function from the knitr package to generate tables from .csv file.

I also have several plots using the base R plot function but these would be stricken to null outputs using the chunk options.

Comment: Instead of making everything 0 or `NA`, you might consider making a lorem ipsum-style document -- that is, numbers are replaced with random numbers that "look" like them. For instance, if you know that a field might have an entry like 201.3, you could replace it with some uniformly distributed number between 100 and 1000, rounded one place beyond the decimal. This will give you a more visually honest representation of what the final layout will be, which is also the point of lorem ipsum text. (Admittedly, this would be far more work than what you're describing, I think.)

Comment: That would work as well, the core of the question remains, is there a global way to do this or do I manually go into each dataset to reset the values.

Comment: It's hard to say how to do this without knowing a bit more about what your document looks like, but I wouldn't ever recommend editing the original datasets. Instead, you could just mask them when you output them as a table / summary / whatever. For instance, if your existing document uses `table(mydf)`, and `mydf` is a rich data frame drawn from a file, then you could use `table(data.frame(x = runif(...), y = runif(...)))` instead. The idea would be to create dummy data on the fly. (I can't say more without seeing more of your document, I think.)

Comment: @Aaron Montgomery , I am usking the "kable" function from the knitr package to generate tables from .csv file. I also have several plots using the base R plot function but these would be stricken to null outputs. I have updated the question to reflect these details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
kable <- function(x, format, digits = getOption("digits"), row.names = NA,
                  col.names = NA, align, caption = NULL, label = NULL,
                  format.args = list(), escape = TRUE, ...){
             x[,] <- 0
             knitr::kable(x, format, digits, row.names, col.names, align,
                      caption, label, format.args, escape, ...)
         }
```

to zero out the `data.frame` before passing to kable.